# Check if input is factor of 100 is not always working correctly in C#

Tags: c#, floating-point, precision

I'm checking if the inputted number is a factor of 100 using the following formula:

`100 % n === 0`

But when someone enters `0.02` it says that `100 % 0.02 = 0.0199999999999979` which is incorrect.

Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

I also tried using: `Math.Abs(100 % 0.02)` but it gives me the same result which is `0.0199999999999979`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the solution also suggests using `Math.Abs()` but rather than comparing it to `0` I need a tolerance value. However, in my case, it should be equal to `0`, because otherwise it would not be a factor of 100.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError no, the expression is correct.

Comment: @OS: Sorry, I misread the question.

Comment: What did you expect to happen using `Math.Abs()`? It just returns the absolute value of a number but does not round it or something.

Comment: @ErikT. I have no idea, Rider IDE suggested it to me as a solution for `Equality comparison of floating point numbers. Possible loss of precision while rounding values.` The top answer in the post @Ahdmed Abdelhameed linked also makes use of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `decimal` seems to be working:

```
100m % 0.02m
```

Output is

```
0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

`0.02` in source code is converted to binary floating-point during compilation. The resulting value is 0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875.

The remainder of 100 divided by 0.0200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875 is 0.0199999999999979187481624620659204083494842052459716796875.

To check if a numeral entered by a user is a multiple of 1/100, either use decimal floating-point or examine the characters the user entered. If they contain no non-zero decimal digits after the second decimal place, the number represented is a multiple of 1/100.